# Saving png file in disk in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the data from what I believe is a png file on a variable like this:

```js
console.log(name, file.value);
```

[image]

How do I properly save that to the filesystem? I've tried all imaginable combinations to save it but they all return something wrong, so the image cannot be opened:

```js
import fsp from 'node:fs/promises';

await fsp.write(name, file.value, "binary");
await fsp.write(name, file.value, "utf8");
await fsp.write(name, Buffer.from([file.value], name), "utf8");
await fsp.write(name, Buffer.from([file.value], name), "binary");
// ...
```

Many of them create the file, but it seems it's wrong and cannot be opened. To get the data here, the original file lives on `/logo.png` so I'm doing on the front-end:

```js
fetch("/logo.png")
  .then((res) => res.blob())
  .then((blob) => {
    const form = new FormData();
    form.append("hello", "world");
    // ...

    form.append("icon.png", new File([blob], "icon.png"));
```

Then to get the data on the front-end I'm doing:

```js
const getBody = async (req) => {
  return await new Promise((done) => {
    const buffers = [];
    req.on("data", (chunk) => {
      buffers.push(chunk);
    });
    req.on("end", () => {
      done(Buffer.concat(buffers).toString("utf8"));
    });
  });
};

const rawData = await getBody(req);

// Parse the rawData to get the fields etc
```

So, my two questions are:

1. What is this data/format called? Binary? can I convert this data format ("Binary?" "etc?

Comment: data format is binary and you can encode it as utf-8. Does this work? `fsp.write(name, Buffer.from(file.value, 'utf-8'));` https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#static-method-bufferfromstring-encoding

Comment: Unfortunately not. Note that the Buffer and FS encoding is `utf8` and not`utf-8`, but that still doesn't work.
Is it possible that I'm messing it up somehow somewhere else? I'm suspicious that my image displaying binary data has so much empty space, and that's why I added my POST and getBody methods, in case I was either sending or parsing it wrongly

Comment: 'utf8' (alias: 'utf-8') https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#static-method-bufferfromstring-encoding

Comment: please try the very same code on a png file that you know is well-formatted.

Comment: If you want binary data (like PNG's) to survive, don't use `toString()` or specify an encoding.

Comment: But I'm receiving my data from a multipart stream in `request`, which effectively mixes strings and binary, how can I _not_ use `.toString()` there to at least first put it all into a string?

Comment: Okay the good news is that if I convert them both to string, they are equal: `console.log('' + file.value ===  '' + temp) => true`. But I cannot seem to convert the `file.value` binary string back to a buffer that matches `temp`, so I agree that once I did use `.toString()` I lost something that cannot be recovered.

Comment: Okay after a while busting my head against doing `.split()` manually in a Buffer, it occured to me to instead transform the buffer to a string _but using_ "binary", and that worked! `done(Buffer.concat(buffers).toString("binary"));` 